# appengine-application.xml fails XML validation

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, google-cloud-tools

I have followed the instructions for configuration of multi-module appengine projects here:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/configuration-files

I copied the appengine-application.xml directly from the example provided, changing only the project name to use a Maven property.  The file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<appengine-application xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
  <application>${appengine.app.name}</application>
</appengine-application>
```

My appengine-application.xml file is located in the following directory structure:

```
projectname-backend/
  src/...
  pom.xml

projectname-common/
  src/...
  pom.xml

projectname-ear/
  src/
    main/
      application/
        META-INF/
          appengine-application.xml
          application.xml
          MANIFEST.MF
  pom.xml

projectname-frontend/
  src/...
  pom.xml
```

Even after cleaning the project, Eclipse is throwing this validation error for the file:

```
cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'appengine-application'.
```

Other files, particularly application.xml in the same directory, are fine.    So it seems to be namespace issue but I can't find any information on what it should be - this is current example in the Google doco.

Any ideas?

Comment: There was a [similar issue reported on the sample GitHub project](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-modules-sample-java/issues/14) with regards. The poster of that issue provided this [Stack Overflow Question / Answer with a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27475714/why-doesnt-maven-property-appengine-app-version-get-interpolated-in-multi-mo/27475715) where he mentions adding a new <configuration> element. Perhaps this might help?

Comment: Thanks @ChristopherP but sadly changing the Maven plugin config doesn't seem to have an impact on the XML validation of appengine-application.xml using the xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0"

Comment: Regarding @ChristopherP comment, might you add to your post a piece of your pom.xml? Lines regarding this:

Comment: <plugin>
    
    <configuration>
        
        <webResources>
           
            <resource>
                <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>